# Resize JPanel within JScrollPane - never smaller than viewport

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I've created a JPanel and JScrollPane like so:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize(5000, 5000);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPanel.getViewport().setBackground(Color.GRAY); //panel is white
```

I will be using event handlers to dynamically resize the panel. The problem is, sometimes the panel is smaller than the viewport. I'd set the panel's size like this:

```
panel.setPreferredSize(10, 10); //Just an example
```

but the panel will never be smaller than the viewport. I tried using

```
panel.setSize(10, 10);
```

and i saw a gray flicker (the viewport's background showing through), which indicated that the panel *was* being sized to what i wanted it to be, but then grew to the viewport's size. How can i stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control the sizing the view inside a JViewport, let it implement the [Scrollable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface. Without, it's always forced to the size of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Just set everything to return null/0/false.